# How to add sql suggest tips

Tags: monaco-editor

There is not the 'SELECT' suggest tip when I input the 's', and what should I do to get that?

```
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container2'), {
  value: '',
  language: 'sql'
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set them through `registerCompletionItemProvider`

```
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('sql', {
    provideCompletionItems: function(model, position) {
        return {
            suggestions: {
                          label: 'select version',
                          kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Property,
                          insertText: 'select @@version'
                         }
        };
    }
});
```

Check in documentation [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-completion-provider-example).

Comment: Thanks,it works after the suggestions return an array value.